# qemu hangs on loading Fedora 20 guest

Tags: fedora, boot, qemu

I launch Qemu in test console:

```
% qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -boot c -hda fedora.qcow2 -snapshot -m 1024 --enable-kvm -name vm0 -curses -pidfile /var/run/vm0.pid -net none -netdev type=tap,id=net0,script=no,downscript=no,ifname=vhost0,vhost=on -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0
```

And it starts booting the kernel, I see messages, however it hangs shortly and all I see on the screen is "1280x1024 Graphic mode" in the center. I don't want any graphics, so I even updated `grub.cfg` on the guest and replaced '`rhgb`' with 'text'.

Also in the guest:

```
% ls -la /etc/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 37 Sep 22 17:17 /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target
%
```

What else should I do to run it in purely text mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to configure your guest to send the console to the serial port.

With grub: $EDITOR /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0 ..."
```

The regenerate grub's config with `grub-mkconfig`

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Once the guest is configured properly. you change your `qemu` command to:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -boot c -hda fedora.qcow2 \
 -snapshot -m 1024 --enable-kvm -name vm0 \
 -pidfile /var/run/vm0.pid -net none \
 -netdev type=tap,id=net0,script=no,downscript=no,ifname=vhost0,vhost=on \
 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0 -nographic
```

Which will use the current terminal for the serial console and qemu monitor console.

If don't want the qemu's monitor console, you can replace `-nographic` with `-serial stdio`